# How can I combine/merge two columns in a dataframe and create a new column that specifies the origin of the data point?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this

```
x1 <- c(1,2,3)
x2 <- c(5,6,7)
df <- data.frame(x1,x2)
```

I would like to combine/merge those two columns x1 and x2 into one column that contains all values. Furthermore I would like to create a new column that says from which of the two columns my datapoint originates. My desired output looks like this:

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
orig <- c("x1","x1","x1","x2","x2","x2")
df_merged <- data.frame(x,orig)
```

I searched a lot for merging, combining, grouping of columns but apparently this is not what the process is called. Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reshaping functions `pivot_longer` in `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
pivot_longer(df, cols = everything())

#  name  value
#  <chr> <dbl>
#1 x1        1
#2 x2        5
#3 x1        2
#4 x2        6
#5 x1        3
#6 x2        7
```

Or `melt` in `data.table` :

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(df))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `stack`

```
> stack(df)
  values ind
1      1  x1
2      2  x1
3      3  x1
4      5  x2
5      6  x2
6      7  x2
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `base R`

```
data.frame(name = rep(names(df), each = nrow(df)), value = unlist(df))
```

---

Or use `gather`

```
library(tidyr)
gather(df)
```